# How to get JWT using POSTMAN?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, postman

I would like the instructions of getting JWT from postman. What are the fields should i add under header and body? It will be nice if there is an example of end to end execution of JWT in postman. Thanks much!

Comment: You neither specified what kind of JWT you want to get and from where nor you wrote what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Tipically JWT works with basic authentication, and in the response body you will obtain the JWT token (and refresh token if it is implemented). In postman you can extract these values into variables in the Tests tab of the request, with something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("jwt_token", data.token);
```

After that you can use the variable jwt_token in any place (urls, headers, body ...) with the syntax {{jwt_token}}

If you need more information about how JWT works in Node.js, you can take a look to this post: https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-with-jwt-authentication-node-js